# Firebase REST API - how to observe and listen for changes

Tags: ios, swift, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The Firebase Swift API provides the method `observeEventType:withBlock` which can be used as follows:

```
 newMessageRefHandle = messageQuery?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

        let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

        if let id = messageData["senderId"] as String!, let name = messageData["senderName"] as String!, let text = messageData["text"] as String!, text.characters.count > 0 {

            self.addMessage(withId: id, name: name, text: text)

        } else {
            print("Error! Could not decode message data")
        }
    })
```

where the completion block gets executed everytime a new child is added. Is there a way to do the same thing using the REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a streaming API for Firebase Realtime Database, and [it's documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-streaming).  From the docs:

> Firebase REST endpoints support the [EventSource / Server-Sent Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/)
>   protocol. To stream changes to a single location in your Realtime
>   Database, you need to do a few things:
>
> - Set the client's Accept header to "text/event-stream"
> - Respect HTTP Redirects, in particular HTTP status code 307
> - If the location requires permission to read, you must include the auth parameter
>
> In return, the server will send named events as the state of the data
>   at the requested URL changes. The structure of these messages conforms
>   to the EventSource protocol.
>
> ```
> event: event name
> data: JSON encoded data payload
> ```

[Click through to the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-streaming) to see all the different events you can expect.